# Sizing a JavaFX stage with a ScrollPane nested in a BorderPane

Tags: java, layout, java-8, javafx-8

In my application I have a `BorderPane` which contains a `ScrollPane` in the center. The `ScrollPane` has two logical sections `top` and `bottom`.

When I create a stage to show the `BorderPane` I want the stage to be sized so that only the `top` section of `ScrollPane` is shown and the user can scroll down to see the `bottom` section if they need it.

So I try to bind the `prefHeight` property of the `ScrollPane` to the `prefHeight` property of the `top` section. Hoping that the `ScrollPane` will get the right height and the stage will look "Just Right™". For some reason this fails miserably. But when I attach a listener to the `prefHeight` property it does indeed return the correct height. So I'm flabbergasted as to what is going on.

Interestingly, if I remove the `BorderPane` it works in the SSCCE but this is not an option in the real case.

**EDIT: SSCCE updated**

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SSCCE extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage aStage) throws Exception {
        VBox top = new VBox(new ComboBox<>(), new ComboBox<>(), new ComboBox<>());
        top.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink");
        top.heightProperty().addListener((aObs, aOld, aNew)->{
            System.out.println(aNew.doubleValue());
        });

        Region regionBottom = new Region();
        regionBottom.setPrefHeight(100);
        regionBottom.setPrefWidth(200);
        regionBottom.setStyle("-fx-background-color: red");

        VBox content = new VBox(top, regionBottom);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
        scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(top.prefHeightProperty());

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
        root.setTop(new MenuBar(new Menu("Foo")));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        aStage.setScene(scene);
        aStage.sizeToScene();
        aStage.show();
        aStage.toFront();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Actual result:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `prefHeightProperty` defaults to a sentinel value, indicating that the pref height should be computed. (`Region.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`). Thus when you bind the `prefHeight` of the scroll pane, you effectively instruct it to do the same, which basically means it will get its default size.

Persuading the layout to be performed and measured in order to get the correct size for the scroll pane's preferred height is a bit of a hack. The correct layout sizes depend on CSS, so you must first force the CSS to be applied, and then you can ask for the computed pref height of the top area. You can do the latter with a call to

```
top.prefHeight(-1);
```

So the following works:

```
    ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(content);
    scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
//    scrollPane.prefHeightProperty().bind(top.heightProperty());


    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(scrollPane);
    root.setTop(new MenuBar(new Menu("Foo")));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    aStage.setScene(scene);

    root.applyCss();
    scrollPane.setPrefHeight(top.prefHeight(-1));
    root.requestLayout();

    aStage.sizeToScene();
    aStage.show();
    aStage.toFront();
```

(Note the call to `aStage.sizeToScene();` is not needed: this is the default behavior anyway.)

Comment: Interesting, while this works in the SSCCE, it doesn't work in the live application. I'm guessing because the `prefSize` isn't set manually there...

Comment: As expected, when the content of top doesn't have a explicit prefHeight set even binding the prefHeightProperty fails (as it is -1).  I have an improved SSCCE, I'm not sure if I should update the OP or make a new question?

Comment: Yes: if you don't set the `prefHeight` it defaults to a sentinel value (`USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`). Update the original question...

Comment: Thank you for your help, although all your suggestions worked on the SSCCE I couldn't get them to work on my live case. Together with other problems that cropped up I decided to go with another UI design to avoid this problem. I'll accept your answer as it did solve the SSCCE.

Comment: I was wondering if a titled pane might work for this use case, with your top area set as the graphic and the bottom area, wrapped in a scroll pane, as the content...